# Why only 1 task is running in 1 executor of Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a spark job where last step is to group by the data according to the date and calculating the count
This step was taking much time so when I checked in Spark UI I could see only one task was running in 1 executor
Remaining all other executors were idle

```
df_missing=spark.sql("select a.tid,a.load_dt from df_all_dates_full a left join df_Del_base b on a.tid=b.tid and a.load_dt=b.load_dt where b.load_dt is Null ").distinct().repartition(100)
df_missing.createOrReplaceTempView("df_missing")

print("Running group by")
spark.sql("select load_dt,count(*) as TID_DEL from df_missing group by  load_dt").show()
```

[image: Spark UI executor page]

Tried by changing the dataframe partition count and changing the executor and driver memory

Answer (score 0):

I think you only see last stage of this query and `groupBy` is executed on that one executor. You have shuffle reads on other workers as well, so they did their job and at the end all data must be pushed on one place to execute grouping.

Try running `explain` on final `DataFrame` it should be relatively obvious.